# com.android.bundle.errors.EvalIssueException: The android Grandle plugin only kotlin-android extension Grandle plugin version

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, kotlin, expo

We have developed an application with react native expo and when we upload the application to the google store the application freezes and does not run. After some research we tried to run our application with Android studio and we get the following error

“com.android.bundle.errors.EvalIssueException: The android Grandle plugin only kotlin-android extension Grandle plugin version. The following dependencies do not satisfy the required verssion:
Project ‘:expo’ -> org.jetbrain.kotlin:kotlin-grandle-plugin:1.6.10
”

The error is most probably occurred because the application is using expo and does not build react native in a native environment. Does any body know how we can solve this problem. Should we change from react native expo to bare react native?

We uploaded successfully the application to the google store and after we download it to our mobile phone, the application did not load and freezed in a white screen. Also the application does not run with android studio and we can not fix this problem.

Comment: It's `gradle` not `grandle`.